# Multiple Buttons keypad in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have been battling with this for three days and asked a LOT of people the question, but maybe I'm asking it wrong. The project that I'm working , is to create a digital safe lock. I need to achieve the following:

I created a keypad with six buttons in a group box. When one click on the buttons, then the digit being clicked must be displayed in the listbox. As you press the rest (up to six digits max) the all have to be displayed in the listbox, next to each other in sequence like the way one will press the buttons on a calculator and then the listbox must display them in the same way. Here is whet I have figured out up to date:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click

        If pinlst.Items.Count = 0 Then
            pinlst.Items.Add(btn1.Text)
        Else
            pinlst.Items(0).SubItems.Add(btn1.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click

        If pinlst.Items.Count = 1 Then
            pinlst.Items.Add(btn2.Text)
        Else
            pinlst.Items(1).SubItems.Add(btn2.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn3.Click

        If pinlst.Items.Count = 2 Then
            pinlst.Items.Add(btn3.Text)
        Else
            pinlst.Items(2).SubItems.Add(btn3.Text)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn4.Click
       pinlst.Text = btn4.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn5.Click
       pinlst.Text = btn5.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn6.Click
        pinlst.Text = btn6.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub btngp_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btngp.Enter
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn1.Text
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn2.Text
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn3.Text
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn4.Text
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn5.Text
        pinlst.Text = pinlst.Text & btn6.Text
   End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: do you have a specific question?  Some of your code suggests you are using a Listview (`pinlst.Items(0).SubItems.Add...`) not a ListBox, but elsewhere `pinLst` is treated differently

Answer (score 0):

It's best to assign every button to a character being pressed or a function being performed, in design time. For this to work, you need to have every button as a custom control, based off a regular button of course, exposing a property "CharPressed" or something like that. Then you can have a single static handler for all buttons, which you will wire dynamically in `Sub New`, after `InitializeComponent`. If this does not make sense, please feel free to ask a question in comments.